# styling a vertical HTML5 range input

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to style a vertical range input and this is what i have:

```
input[type='range'] {
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 158px;
    width: 2px;
    margin: 8px auto;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #3ebede;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

but it seems that because i have '**-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;**' to make it vertical,
styles won't apply.

Is there a way to style a vertical range without transforms/plugins...?

*Note: I only need it to work on Chrome*

**UPDATE:**
Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amirush/qG49s/) for what I have.

Comment: Have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EVhY9/) from me :)

Comment: So you need to use [these other selectors](http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html). [Here are some of those in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVhY9/1/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So this is an answer, I guess. You need to use other selectors. [Read more here](http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html).

`-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);` - Make it vertical, tweak margins to suit.

[Google is your friend!](https://www.google.com/#q=range+style+chrome)

From the article:

> WEBKIT BASED BROWSERS (CHROME, SAFARI, OPERA)
>
> In webkit based browsers, the track is styled with a special pseudo selector `::-webkit-slider-runnable-track`, and the thumb with `::webkit-slider-thumb`.
>
> Custom focus styles can also be applied on the thumb and the track. If you go that route, you'll have to remove default focus styles on the input itself.

Here is [an example in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVhY9/1/). CSS taken from my previous source.

HTML

```
<input type="range" />
```

CSS

```
input[type=range]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: goldenrod;
    margin-top: -4px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Well, this isn't what I wanted - the selectors are fine, 
they just dont seem to work with 
'-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical' 
which I use to make it vertical.

Comment: Get creative! `-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);` [Here with a vertical transform](http://jsfiddle.net/EVhY9/2/)

Comment: I feel like you didn't actually read what I've asked - 
Is this possible without transform?

Comment: From what I gather using my google-fu, no. I could be wrong, but the only way it seems to style the range input is to remove `-webkit-appearance` and recreate the slider styles. This is a pretty neat solution, no? You essentially asked for a vertical slider, here is a vertical slider :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess there's no other option. Thanks!

Comment: @Resonance - note that I say "`transform:rotate(90deg);` - Make it vertical, tweak margins to suit." which addresses the vertical aspect of the question.

Comment: It is not that clear where that line needs to be added. IMHO if you add that line under `input[type=range]{`  (or wherever you think it should go) in both your JS fiddle and answer it would make this a lot easier to understand. Thanks

Comment: `-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);` is buggy on touch devices